# Jenkins remote API - is it possible to retrieve the complete job tree using the Jenkins tree query api without knowing the depth?

Tags: jenkins, tree

When using the folders plugin on Jenkins, jobs are ordered in a tree. I need to retrieve all jobs using the tree query remote api, without know the trees depth.

Eg

```
api/json?tree=jobs[name,jobs[name,jobs[name]]]&pretty=true
```

will return all job names from the root of the tree, and the two next levels. Ideally I would like a query that just gives me all job names.

Is this possible? The tree query api is pretty much undocumented... (I experimented with * but that just returns all properties)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no I didn't but meanwhile we have Jenkins Enterprise support, I'll open a ticket and ask Cloudbees. I'll keep you posted

Comment: i have answered my own question

Comment: no better solution ?

Comment: no sorry, that is what Cloudbees themselves said

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have meanwhile asked this to Cloudbees themselves. You either ask all info with the depth parameter, or you manually concatenate the parameters. Either way you need to know the depth.

```
api/json?depth=3&pretty
```

or

```
api/json?tree=jobs[name,buildable,jobs[name,buildable,jobs[name,buildable]]]&pretty
```

Comment: In case anyone needs it but doesn't use the REST client directly with the freedom to manipulate the query, the Jenkins groovy script console gives me what I need: `println Jenkins.instance.getAllItems().collect {it.fullName}`