# Getting all Jenkins jobs in a single http request with tree or depth parameter

Tags: api, rest, jenkins

I currently have a Jenkins instance with around 800 jobs. The directory structure has some nested folders with jobs in each level. Although I think this is not the optimal way to set up Jenkins that is out of my control. I'm currently using the Jenkins API to get information from these jobs trough a node JS environment.

I have tried two things (both of these approaches work, but they are causing some issues):

- Recursively call the directory structure from the root and check if I get a job with the _class 'workflowjob' and use the tree=jobs[*] to get the apiURL and jobs within the folder.
- I have tried assigning depth = N to a high enough N and get all the information in one json object.

Now the first approach is great if my Jenkins instance was smaller, but too many calls is causing issues and bringint it down.

While the second approach is also great, the directory structure can cahnge in the future and hardcoding the N value is not the most ideal. Also the returned object is not ideal for parsing.

I have also tried to limit the amount of jobs with tree=jobs[*]{n, n-1} but its not ideal since I want to keep all of them.

I have also tried the groovy scripts but not sure that will integrate well with my node environment.

Is there a better/alternative way to use the REST API to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I will not have a very *happy* and satisfying answer to you as there's no API to support "get all jobs" - **so there's nothing better for API** (there's even already an open ticket requesting this feature from 2016): https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-39774

**But possible approaches** are either:

- use groovy script that supports this kind of call, e.g.:

```
println Jenkins.instance.getAllItems().collect {it.fullName}
```

OR

- (via REST API) This was actually and discussed before and responded as well ([Jenkins remote API - is it possible to retrieve the complete job tree using the Jenkins tree query api without knowing the depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236206/jenkins-remote-api-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-complete-job-tree-using-the) . This could lead to a potential solution (if necessary to use API calls) to set at least some pauses in between your request so you don't overwhelm your system with one huge request to process and also not send to many requests in burst.

---

Historical discussions on this topic (but mentioning more or less the same):

- [Jenkins remote API - is it possible to retrieve the complete job tree using the Jenkins tree query api without knowing the depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236206/jenkins-remote-api-is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-complete-job-tree-using-the)
- https://groups.google.com/g/jenkinsci-users/c/3drn20pK2Fs
- https://gist.github.com/justlaputa/5634984